# App is rejecting due to presence of auto renewing subscription but actually not available neither in binary nor in iTunes account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

From the Admin Panel

[image]

I have removed auto renewing subscription from iTunes developer account but still app is rejected. I got the reason from Apple:

> "However upon further review we still find that you have submitted
>   auto-renewing subscription in-app purchase products for your app.
>   However, the auto-renewing subscription in-app purchase functionality
>   is not present in your binary."

However, I did not find any option to delete the subscription group but there is no product is available for auto renewing subscription.

Not sure why app is getting reject and how auto renewing subscription is submitted for review.

Answer (score 0):

Was is the first submission to the app store for this app? 
If so, make sure, you do not have any inApp purchases added to the app for review (on the app or version information page).

If that is all fine, so your app does not offer any inApp purchases and you do not have any inApp purchases associated with your app, I think you should simply explain this to your reviewer by sending an answer to the rejection message in the resolution center.

If you are not sure, what you are supposed to do, just tell them so. They'll help you out - at least that's my experience :)

Comment: This is first submission on app store. Non-cosumable IAP is added. Auto renewing subscription was added earlier but it is removed now. App description is updated after removing auto-rening-subscription. But apple is rejecting the app just saying: "However upon further review we still find that you have submitted auto-renewing subscription in-app purchase products for your app. However, the auto-renewing subscription in-app purchase functionality is not present in your binary."

Comment: I see, in this case I recommend you explain it to the reviewer just like you did here.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. My app (first submission) is staying "in review" due to an unused subscription group that is not needed anymore. Review team requests to delete the group, but this is technically impossible. Since the app is still "in Review" I can't reach the developer. Any ideas how to reach review team beyond "developer reject" ?